# What is the matter with this Shimano disc brake lever?

Tags: brakes, bike-fit, ergonomics

I got the BR-M445L + BL-M505L a month ago. I am new to hydraulic disc brakes, so I can't tell if there is any problem with air in the system or other problems. Asked a mechanic and he said the brake is fine, though.

I am unsure how to describe the problem. The lever feels *awkward*. The pivot point of the lever is too far forward (compared to Avid Elixir and other levers with the oil cylinder along the hose direction). I feel as if the lever is just too far from my fingers to comfortably squeeze. And I can't reduce the reach from the adjustment screw, because it then hits against my glove.

The problem is bad enough when using 2 fingers, but is terrible when using only one finger - the lever hits my middle finder and the travel is insufficient to actuate the brake.

**Is there something fundamentally wrong with this lever design, at least for some cyclists. Or some trick that is a must-do (I installed the already bled system myself)?**

My brake:

[image]

"Normal" brakes:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use these brakes 1 fingered, I would recommend moving them to the inside of your shifters to remove the overlap with your middle finger.

I have all my brakes set up like this and it works great.

[image: Inboarded brake lever]

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Unfortunately my [acera front shifter](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/4142WWbN64L.jpg) is quite bulky on the inside so the brake can't stick up to it.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. Have you tried leaving the brakes outboard and moving the brake and shifter inwards together? There might be a sweet sop where the brakes are far enough away but the shifters close enough.

Comment: Both the answer and this commend are great advice to anyone (thus accepting). The real problem was that some oil had leaked through the sealings. I am new to hydraulic brakes and didn't know.