# Is it bad to keep hydraulic brakes engaged for many hours?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake

I find it easier to park my bike if I can remove one of its degrees of freedom, for example, prevent the wheels from rotating. An easy way to do this would be to strap one of the brake levers down.

This would be for around 8–12 hours, 5–6 times per week. I have hydraulic disc brakes. The bike would be [upright](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/).

I have a feeling that this is a bad idea. Is it? And if so, why?

Comment: Why does the brake need to be engaged after you park it? I don't see why it would matter, but you could always just strap the wheels instead.

Comment: @Batman, for example, it prevents the bike from tipping over if the handlebars turn, and it makes parking on an incline easier. Where I live, it's extremely hilly, so that comes up a lot. Also, I don't have enough hands to squeeze the lever and chain it up at the same time. As for strapping the wheels, that's another approach, but the brake levers are already there and handy.

Comment: Most hydraulics will "leak down" over time.  In the worst case the fluid will leak out of the wheel cylinder, but more likely is fluid leaking past the piston/valve in the lever.  How fast this will happen is hard to predict, but generally bike brake levers would not be designed to withstand pressure for more than a few minutes.

Comment: Why not use the same strap to stop the wheel directly? E.g. strap the wheel to the fork.

Comment: My tandem has a drum brake which is intended for this, the hydraulic brakes are not.   If you're keen on a brake, look at either a drum brake or an axxa dutch lock to stop your bike rolling.  Or lock it to something like a bike stand.

Comment: You can also find disc locks that will prevent it from turning, and give you 1 more save to the bike.

Comment: Strapping the wheel directly would be a recipe for desaster for me - I would likely, by Murphys Law, at some point, forget it and drive off with strap in place...

Comment: @Daniel, I wonder if you might promote your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Criggie as well, that seems like it could be an answer.

Comment: @ChrisH, the wheel would need a longer and wider strap.

Comment: @reid - mine's a comment because it doesn't actually answer your question about why it would be bad to pressurise brakes for hours on end.  The Axa lock is here  http://www.dutchbikebits.com/axa-defender-wheel-lock as an example.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer?  No, it will not generally cause you a problem.  This is actually a common method of parking a loaded touring bike.

Don't over tension the brake lever.  Remember that a hydraulic lever doesn't require excessive force to have power at the brake.

A simple 6mm rubberband wrapped over the lever and handlebar should accomplish your purpose.

[image]